# JGraphT graph visit/travel use case

Tags: jgrapht

I am new to JGraphT, and i have a use case, say a simple graph, A->B->C, and have (timed) events representing visiting the vertices, and they can come out of order, for example, event B (visits B) comes in first with event time (9:02), since it is the first, create a instance of the graph 1 (A->B->C) with B noted as visited. then event A comes in next with event time (9:00), since A is before (event time) B, and within a range (say 10 minute), A and B belong to the same graph instance, so I add A to instance 1, so now instance 1 has two vertices visited A and B.

I am wondering if anyone can give some suggestions/guide/direction as how JGraphT can help, with my custom implementation if necessary.

What I need;

1. Check if a new visit event (vertex) fits in an existing graph (instance) with my own logic to check event time.
2. Give me all the vertices visited for a graph (instance).

Comment: Quite frankly I have no clue what you want to do. This question has nothing to do with JGraphT. To check whether a vertex is visited, simply keep a Set<V> of visited vertices. To check whether a vertex is in a graph, invoke mygraph.containsVertex(v); To add a vertex to a graph: mygraph.addVertex(v)....

Comment: Thanks for reply, i was wondering if there is a way to add/plug my data/logic into the graph and use existing APIs, for example instead of keep a Set<V> outside of the graph i was looking if i can store this in the graph and have a simple/easy way to get/aggregate the data. As i read more, i think i have some ideas what i can do in the graph and what needs to be done outside.